# Operator with every complex number as an eigenvalue

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

The question :

> Let $V$ be the space of all functions $f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb C$. Find an operator $T : V \to V$ such that every $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ is an eigenvalue i.e. for every $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ , there is some non-zero $f$ such that $Tf = \lambda f$.

This question is surprising, in light of the fact that for a Banach algebra,  the spectrum is a compact subset. So this shows that $V$ cannot be given a Banach algebra structure.

For this question, my idea was to hope that $V$ has an uncountable Hamel basis $e_i : i \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ . I would then have $T$ such that $Te_1 = 0$,$Te_2 = e_1$, $Te_3 = 2e_2$,..., along with $Te_l = le_l$ for every other $l \neq 1,2,...$. This would work.

I was not able to find such a Hamel basis : I tried using indicator functions of subsets of $\mathbb Z$, but I need a *concrete example*(i.e. I am aware that a Hamel basis for $V$ exists and must be uncountable, but I need the exact form of the $e_i$), and I am not able to find one.

Comment: Should $T$ be continuous ?

Comment: No, it does not need to be continuous.

Comment: The spectrum of a non-continuous operator of a Banach algebra need not be compact as far as I know... Take for example some basis (with axiom of choice) and define $T$ to be diagonal for this basis, with arbitrary scalars, then this is a well defined (non continuous) operator on $V$ which has a non compact spectrum

Comment: Now that you say it, yes you are right. However, I am seeking a concrete example.

Comment: With axiom of choice, you only need to find an uncountable independent family of vectors of $V$, because then you can set $T$ as I said, putting every scalar of $\mathbb C$ for a certain vector, and then extending it to the whole space (this is where I think AC is needed). For such a family, maybe the $n\mapsto e^{\lambda n}$ would do but it remains to be shown

Comment: Yes, I shall think about what you said.

Comment: What makes you think that there exists such an operator? Especially since, as you write, you want a **concrete example**?

Comment: Could you do a tensor product of, say, the position operator - which has spectrum the whole real line - and an operator that has spectrum equal to the unit circle like the unilateral shift (I think) ?

Comment: @Somos It was a question in an exam (not given by me), and I know the person who made the paper. Also, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think this should do the trick (but it is not nice).
For $t>0$, define $$f_t(n)=e^{-nt}$$
Then if $$\sum_{0\leq i\leq k}\lambda_if_{t_i}=0$$
take $i_0$ such that $t_{i_0}=\max\{t_i,\ 0\leq i\leq k \text{ and }\lambda_i\neq0\}$.

Then, $$\sum_{0\leq i\leq k}\lambda_if_{t_i}\sim_{n\to+\infty}\lambda_{i_0}e^{-nt_{i_0}}$$
so that $\lambda_{i_0}=0$, so actually the $(f_t)_t$ are independant.

Now let $\phi$ be a bijection between $\mathbb R_+^*$ and $\mathbb C$, and let
$$g_\lambda:=f_{\phi^{-1}(\lambda)}$$
for $\lambda\in\mathbb C$.

The $(g_\lambda)_\lambda$ are independant so you can complete this family to form a basis $\mathcal B$.

Define $T$ for each element of the basis by $T(g_\lambda)=\lambda g_\lambda$ and $T(b)=0$ for $b\in\mathcal B\setminus\{g_\lambda\}_\lambda$.

This yields a well defined operator $T$ on $V$ which has every complex number as eigenvalue, so that $\text{Sp}\ T=\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you require $T$ to be a linear operator.
Define $T$ to be the shift operator $(Tf)(n) = f(n+1)$. For any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$, consider $f_\lambda (n) = \lambda^n$, then 
$Tf_\lambda = \lambda f_\lambda.$

Comment: Ah, very nice! Certainly $T$ is linear. Also, every $\lambda \neq 0$ is an eigenvalue, clearly. Can you show that $T$ has non-trivial kernel i.e. $0$ is an eigenvalue? In fact, I don't think zero is an eigenvalue, because if $Tf \equiv 0$ then $f \equiv 0$ i.e. $T$ is injective. However, I think a slight modification of $T$ should do the trick. I will think about this.

Comment: You are right. In this case, $0$ is not an eigenvalue...

Comment: With a small modification this can be done: set $(Tf)(0)=0$ and $(Tf)(-1)=f(1)$.